# Relation Between Eigenvalues of Block Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there any relation between eigenvalues, or spectral radii, of $M$, $M_1$, and $M_2$ block matrices?

\begin{equation}
M=
\begin{bmatrix}
A&B\\B^T&C
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
M_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&B\\B^T&C
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
M_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
A&0\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Noting that these matrices are symmetric and applying the [spectral norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpectralNorm.html), we have
$$
\rho(M) = \|M\| = \|M_1 + M_2\| \leq \|M_1\| + \|M_2\| = \rho(M_1) + \rho(M_2)
$$
We also have (for similar reasons)
$$
\rho(M_1) \geq |\rho(M) - \rho(M_2)|\\
\rho(M_2) \geq |\rho(M) - \rho(M_1)|
$$
As for the eigenvalues, we could apply the [Weyl inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl.27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Omnomnomnom! But your answer does not look to be correct. I have a simple counterexample:

\begin{equation}
M=M_1+M_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
M_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
M_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
We have $\rho(M) = 1$ and $\rho(M_1) = \rho(M_2) = 0$.